# Motorcycle stalls shortly after starting

Tags: engine, electrical, motorcycle, oil

I have a BMW 2008 F 800 st and the oil looks watery. It stops pretty frequently after riding it around the block. When it stalls, after some hesitation, it will start again.

I need an unbiased answer because the motorcycle is salvage. It does run just seems to give out soon after.

It does not seem like the battery has anything to do with it. It feels like the bike shakes; we have escaped like noise from the motor, I wonder if it could be something simple like an oil change, all fluids or maybe even needs more water.

Also it has a slip on exhaust which is missing. I'm not sure if that's enough exposure for things to get inside; if so what possible things can go wrong?

Comment: also it has a slip on exhaust which is missing idk if thats  exposed enough for things to get inside

Comment: Isnt hot oil  the result of it looking watery.

Comment: is a head gasket repairable without replacing it

Comment: Viik, have you resolved the issue.  I'm actually thinking this is related to fuel system and the bike sitting idle for too long before you bought it salvage.  If you are still having issues, please update and someone will be happy to assist.  If one of the resonders was correct please award them the answer.   Cheers to you!

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I think of when I hear 'watery oil' is a bad head gasket. That could cause a lot of the issues you are experiencing.

> we have escaped like noise from the motor

Can you explain what that means?

> I wonder if it could be something simple like an oil change, all fluids or maybe even needs more water.

It might be a good idea to change the oil and certainly a good idea to check your fluid levels, but it is doubtful that your fluid levels (unless entirely missing) are causing your issues.

> Also it has a slip on exhaust which is missing. I'm not sure if that's enough exposure for things to get inside; if so what possible things can go wrong?

The missing exhaust is not likely the cause of the issues you described here.

Comment: Is some thing clogged

Answer (score 2):

Running without an exhaust will cause the bike to run a little leaner.  if its already lean you may be overheating the engine (correct air/fuel mix also cools the cylinders) which in turn will affect the oil which will also affect the engine.

Watery oil to me means one thing, its broken down so is thinner than it should be and not lubricating how it should.  If it was water mixed in oil then it would be thicker and resemble mayonnaise in texture.

Can you describe the noise from the engine? is it a thumping noise (almost like a hammer), is the noise in time with the engine, or at half engine speed, or not related to engine speed at all?

I would:

1. change the oil and oil filter immediately
2. inspect the spark plugs for colour: white electrode/anode = lean burning; black and sooty = too rich
3. add an exhaust as soon as you can - this will help the engine disperse heat better